# Betti numbers for the isotropic grassmannian

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, representation-theory, schubert-calculus

I want to know if there is some type of combinatorial formula for computing the Betti numbers of the isotropic grassmannian $IG(r,2n)$ for $r\leq n$.

I'm thinking of this as the homogenous space $G/P$ where $G=Sp(2n)$, and $P$ is the maximal parabolic generated by the subset of simple roots $S-{\alpha_r}$, where $S={\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n}$ are the simple roots for $Sp(2n)$.

I know in the case of the Grassmannian $Gr(r,n)$ the $i^{th}$ Betti number is the number of partitons of the integer $i$ which can for inside a $r\times (n-r)$ box. These are the coefficients of the Poicare series of the Grassmanian which happens to be the Gaussian polynomial or q-binomial coefficient
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-BinomialCoefficient.html

So I wonder if there is a similar combinatorial description for the betti numbers of the isotropic grassmannian or it the Poincare Series has a known form. I can write down the Poincare series for the isotrpic Grassmannian, but its not clear to me if this has some more well-known form.

In particular I'd like to know whether $dim(H^i(IG,r,2n))$ is still bound by the number of partitions of the integer $i$ ?

Comment: The $i$th Betti number is the number of strict partitions of $i$ with all parts $\le n$. I'd write a full answer but I'm about to head to bed.

Comment: Oh, you're allowing $r<n$. That's a bit uglier, but there's still a combinatorial description. You could look at some papers by my advisor, Anders Buch.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the suggestion. From this paper https://www.math.rutgers.edu/~asbuch/papers/qgig.pdf                             It seems the $i^{th}$ Betti number of $IG(n-k,2k)$ is the number of k-strict partitions of $i$ which fit into a $n-k\times n+k$ rectangle

Comment: Sounds right. And no problem.

Comment: By the way, if you know about Coxeter groups and the relation to the Betti numbers it's a good exercise to prove this yourself. You can decompose the minimal length coset representatives into the product of a type $A$ representative and a maximal type $B$ representative. It can be done with utterly elementary reasoning. I had fun with it at least!